# open cv finds strange contours

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I took a picture with a raspbery pi camera clone and want to find the contours in in. OpenCV doesn't seem to find the contours I was expecting. Is there an error in my code ?

```
image0=cv2.imread('picture.png',0) 
image=cv2.medianBlur(image0,3)
cnts,_=cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
image=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.drawContours(image,cnts,-1,(0,0,255),thickness=1)
cv2.imshow('image',image0)
cv2.imshow('edged',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance :).
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The missing step is applying [threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

The threshold result will be:

[image]

Now find the contours:

[image]

Code:

---

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("bugs.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cnt, _ = cv2.findContours(thr, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(img, cnt, -1, (0, 0, 255), thickness=1)
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: thanks, I guess that's what I was missing :). Do you have any idea if there's a possibility to somehow get the whole contours as there are always parts missing when I treshold before searching for the contours ?